# How to build a list faster than .append?

Tags: python, list, performance, append

I have tried this code

```
p = 1000003
q = 400003
M = p*q  
n = 84480
X = [6225**2%M]
new = X[0]**2%M
i = 1
while new not in X and len(X) < n:
         X.append(new)
         new = X[i]**2%M
         i += 1
```

`.append` syntax took a while to build the list. I need another syntax to make a list faster because `n` is quite large.

Answer (score 3):

You can try Python's `extend()` method which is faster than append.
For large lists, the runtime of the `extend()` method is 60% faster than the runtime of the `append()` method.
[more info](https://blog.finxter.com/python-list-append-vs-extend/)

Comment: How extend can improve performances? he add only one element per step, so extend will work like append

Comment: @Glauco the extend() method should be faster for larger list sizes because Python can append elements to a list in a batch rather than by calling the same method again and again.

Comment: I agree with your point of view, but in **this** algorithm he insert only one item a time

Comment: @Glauco He said in his question "I need another syntax to make a list faster because n is quite large." so that's why I advised him to try to `extend()`.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. Would be nice to also write down the changed code in question. Extend() needs to add the element as a tuple, you have to add () around the value you want to extend.

Answer (score 2):

Python works well if you don't instantiate or change object at runtime, so if you create **all** elements as first step, you can simply reassign values.
But this algorithm lack in the **[new in X]** part, this because this is O(NxM).

So the best solution is create all element before in order to avoid append, and use a better data structure to check if values is altready done, this is a dictionary:

```
p = 1000003
q = 400003
M = p*q  
n = 84480
X = [6225**2%M]*n
Xd = {X[0]:None}
new = X[0]**2%M
i = 1
while new not in Xd and i<n:
         X[i] = new
         Xd[new]=None
         new = X[i]**2%M
         i += 1



Original:
CPU times: user 47.5 s, sys: 13.2 ms, total: 47.5 s
Wall time: 49.5 s

Optimized:
CPU times: user 66.9 ms, sys: 9 µs, total: 66.9 ms
Wall time: 103 ms
```

Comment: i see, the point is built the list at the beginning. Thanks a lot bro

Comment: but, now i have 1 list and 1 tuple, is that not take a while?

Comment: That is not a tuple but a dictionary, and it is blazing fast for the **in** operation.

(x in []   takes O(n)) ( x in {} takes O(1))  so this is the second improvement.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is not with append but with the way you check for existence of a duplicate entry.  You can use a set to do that very efficiently.

You can also structure the code as a generator to make it easier to use and reuse:

```
def modSquare(N,M,maxCount):
    seen = set()
    for _ in range(maxCount):
        N = N**2%M
        if N in seen: break
        yield N
        seen.add(N)
```

output:

```
p = 1000003
q = 400003
M = p*q  
n = 84480
X = list(modSquare(6225,M,n))

print(len(X)) 
# 84480

print(X[:3],"...",X[-3:])
# [38750625, 395175256848, 7948406859] ... [166985992167, 267628307961, 385065196277]
```